# Use HTML instead of HAML with Ruby on Rails Happy Seed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

How can I use html.erb instead of haml when using a rails application that is generated using happy seed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to do anything special. 
You could convert your `haml` code to `erb` using https://haml2erb.org and then create an `erb` file pasting the code. Also delete the haml file. This should work.

Comment: maybe remove the gem haml too, because if you generate scaffold you will have haml file by default.

Comment: @johan I dont think you need to remove haml gem unless you dont plan to use it all.